# Listview items duplicated on clicking notification

Tags: android, listview

I am getting listView items duplicated if I play a song in the background and go back to the app on clicking the notification icon. While opening the app for the first time, items are not duplicated. What could be wrong? Posting below my adapter class.

Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final int pos = position;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_song_title);
        holder.tvArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_song_artist);
        holder.imgAlbumArt = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img_lv_album_art);

        holder.tvArtist.setText(songs.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.tvTitle.setText(songs.get(position).getTitle());

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    int id = (int) songs.get(position).getId();

    if (bitmaps == null) {
        Bitmap bm = MainActivity.getCachedArtwork(mContext,
                id, MainActivity.getDefaultArtwork(mContext));
        holder.imgAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bitmaps.put(id, bm);
        Log.d("inside null", "key=" + id + "bm=" + bm + "pos" + position);
    } else if (bitmaps.containsKey(id)) {
        Bitmap bm = bitmaps.get(id);
        holder.imgAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bitmaps.put(id, bm);
        Log.d("inside contains key", "key=" + id + "bm=" + bm + "pos"
                + position);
    } else {
        Bitmap bm = MainActivity.getCachedArtwork(mContext,
                id, MainActivity.getDefaultArtwork(mContext));

        holder.imgAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bitmaps.put(id, bm);
        Log.d("inside else", "key=" + id + "bm=" + bm + "pos" + position);
    }
  return view;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public static Bitmap getCachedArtwork(Context context, int artIndex,
        Bitmap defaultArtwork) {
    Bitmap d = null;
    synchronized (sArtCache) {
        d = sArtCache.get(artIndex);
    }
    if (d == null) {
        d = defaultArtwork;
        final Bitmap icon = defaultArtwork;
        int w = icon.getWidth();
        int h = icon.getHeight();
        Bitmap b = getArtworkQuick(context, artIndex, w, h);
        if (b != null) {
            d = b;// new FastBitmapDrawable(b);
            synchronized (sArtCache) {
                // the cache may have changed since we checked
                Bitmap value = sArtCache.get(artIndex);
                if (value == null) {
                    sArtCache.put(artIndex, d);
                } else {
                    d = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return d;
}

// Get album art for specified album. This method will not try to
// fall back to getting artwork directly from the file, nor will
// it attempt to repair the database.
private static Bitmap getArtworkQuick(Context context, int album_id, int w, int h) {
    // NOTE: There is in fact a 1 pixel frame in the ImageView used to
    // display this drawable. Take it into account now, so we don't have to
    // scale later.
    w -= 2;
    h -= 2;
    ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
    if (uri != null) {
        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = null;
        try {
            fd = res.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            int sampleSize = 1;

            // Compute the closest power-of-two scale factor 
            // and pass that to sBitmapOptionsCache.inSampleSize, which will
            // result in faster decoding and better quality
            sBitmapOptionsCache.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                    fd.getFileDescriptor(), null, sBitmapOptionsCache);
            int nextWidth = sBitmapOptionsCache.outWidth >> 1;
            int nextHeight = sBitmapOptionsCache.outHeight >> 1;
            while (nextWidth>w && nextHeight>h) {
                sampleSize <<= 1;
                nextWidth >>= 1;
                nextHeight >>= 1;
            }

            sBitmapOptionsCache.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            sBitmapOptionsCache.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                    fd.getFileDescriptor(), null, sBitmapOptionsCache);

            if (b != null) {
                // finally rescale to exactly the size we need
                if (sBitmapOptionsCache.outWidth != w || sBitmapOptionsCache.outHeight != h) {
                    Bitmap tmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, w, h, true);
                    b.recycle();
                    b = tmp;
                }
            }


            return b;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fd != null)

                    fd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the adapter data? Maybe you're adding items twice?

Comment: I am setting it only once in Activity's onCreate method.Also listview height is set to match_parent only.

Comment: Well that is pretty much the only possibility. It's not only the listview, it's the underlying data that has the duplicate entries (could be a list or a cursor). Add some logs in the code that show you exactly how many items you have in the data and what exactly you're adding.

Comment: You are right . List size is getting doubled every time I go the app again. Not able to figure out where its getting added again.

Comment: Found the error. I had declared List as static. My mistake . Thanks for your response.